# Latest records using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to build weekly aggregated data for sales. Where `TRNST_QTY`is the latest available quantity of the closing week and `PRCHS_QTY` is the sum of purchase quantity for the particular week. I have date dimension where date key and corresponding week key is present.

If there is any week there is no transaction happened it should take the last week's `TRNST_QTY` and `PRCHS_QTY` will be `0`

***Table 1 (Sales table):***

```
DT_KEY      ITEM    TRNST_QTY   PRCHS_QTY
20160515    4098    2               1
20160516    4098    10              1
20160601    4098    4               0
20160603    4098    8               0
20160611    4098    6               4
20160616    4098    4               0
20160622    4098    8               0
20160623    4098    2               0
20160714    4098    11              3
```

**Output required(weekly aggregate):**

```
WK_DT_KEY   ITEM    TRNST_QTY   PRCHS_QTY
20160521    4098    10          2
20160607    4098    8           0
20160614    4098    6           4
20160621    4098    4           0
20160630    4098    2           0
20160707    4098    2           0
20160714    4098    11          3
```

**Date & Week mapping:**

```
DT_KEY      WK_DT_KEY
20160515    20160521
20160516    20160521
20160517    20160521
20160518    20160521
20160519    20160521
20160520    20160521
20160521    20160521
20160601    20160607
20160602    20160607
20160603    20160607
20160604    20160607
```

and so on

So far I am able to below query but its giving only latest week information

```
select * from 
(
SELECT WK_DT_KEY
    ,ITEM
    ,sum(PRCHS_QTY) OVER (
        PARTITION BY WK_DT_KEY
        ,ITEM
        ORDER BY WK_DT_KEY
            ,ITEM
        ) AS PRCHS_QTY
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY ITEM order by a.dt_key desc
        ) AS RNK
FROM fct_itm a
    ,DIM_DT DIM_DT
WHERE a.dt_key <= '20170207'
    AND DIM_DT.DT_key = a.dt_key
)
where RNK = 1;
```

I want to avoid procedural approach or connect by clause. 
I will be grateful any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DIM_DT.WK_DT_KEY,
       A.ITEM,
       SUM(A.PRCHS_QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY DIM_DT.WK_DT_KEY,A.ITEM) AS PRCHS_QTY,
       FIRST_VALUE(A.TRNST_QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ITEM,DIM_DT.WK_DT_KEY
                                      ORDER BY A.DT_KEY DESC) AS TRNS_QTY
FROM FCT_ITM A
JOIN DIM_DT DIM_DT ON DIM_DT.DT_KEY = A.DT_KEY
WHERE A.DT_KEY <= '20170207'
```

Notes:

- Use the `FIRST_VALUE` function to get the latest trnst_qty for each week.
- ORDER BY isn't required in the `SUM` as you are getting the total and not running total.
- Always use explicit `join` syntax instead of `,` s in the `where` clause.
- Use appropriate aliases before column names.

Edit: Per OP's comment, to get the last non-null value for weeks missing transactions, use `LAG` with `IGNORE NULLS` option.

```
SELECT 
WK_DT_KEY,
ITEM,
CASE WHEN TRNS_QTY IS NULL THEN LAG(TRNS_QTY IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITITON BY ITEM ORDER BY WK_DT_KEY)
ELSE TRNS_QTY END AS TRNS_QTY,
PRCHS_QTY
FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT D.WK_DT_KEY,
  D.ITEM,
  SUM(COALESCE(A.PRCHS_QTY,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY D.WK_DT_KEY,D.ITEM) AS PRCHS_QTY,
  FIRST_VALUE(A.TRNST_QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY D.ITEM,D.WK_DT_KEY
                                                  ORDER BY A.DT_KEY DESC) AS TRNS_QTY
  FROM
   (SELECT DT.WK_DT_KEY,DT.DT_KEY,F.ITEM
    FROM DIM_DT DT
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM FROM FCT_ITM) F) D --cross join items with all dates and week combinations
  LEFT JOIN FCT_ITM A ON D.DT_KEY = A.DT_KEY AND D.ITEM=A.ITEM 
  AND A.DT_KEY <= '20170207' 
 ) X
```

Comment: @vkp Thanks! . There are some weeks where I dont have transaction . I need to get the data for that week too. For example `20160707` week dosent ave any transaction so it should pick the trnst_qty from `20160630   ` week and `PRCHS_QTY` is zero .

Comment: what if there are 2 or more weeks missing values? should the values be picked up from the most recent available week?

Comment: @vkp yeah exactly this is the requirement.

Comment: which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @vkp am using 11g

Comment: @vkp Thanks! Is there any other alternatives besides cross join as the data volume is in .5 billion in transaction table

Comment: @luminita .. see the edit..i modified it to only get items from transactions table.. the cross join is needed as you have to pairup item with all dates and weeks to show missing rows.